# Code formatting error for no reason

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I have Mathematica code that I am trying to post, but to no avail. No matter what I try, I am still getting the code formatting error.

The code is this:

```
{18 wbcd^3 - 192 w^2 bde^2 + 18 b^3 cde + 144 wb^2 ce^2 - 4 wc^3 d^2 +
   b^2 c^2 d^2 - 4 b^3 d^3 - 27 w^2 d^4 - 80 wbc^2 de + 16 wc^4 e - 4 b^2 c^3 e + 144 w^2 cd^2 e - 6 wb^2 d^2 e - 27 b^4 e^2 - 128 w^2 c^2 e^2 + 256 w^3 e^3}
 /.{w -> a^2, b -> 2 a h ,
  c -> h^2 - 1, d -> 2 u , e -> G Q^2 }
```

with the results like this:

```
{-192 a^4 bde^2 + 144 a^3 cde h^3 + 144 a^4 cd^2 G Q^2 -
  16 a^2 G h^2 (-1 + h^2)^3 Q^2 - 432 a^4 G^2 h^4 Q^4 -
  128 a^4 G^2 (-1 + h^2)^2 Q^4 + 256 a^6 G^3 Q^6 +
  16 a^2 h^2 (-1 + h^2)^2 u^2 - 256 a^3 h^3 u^3 - 432 a^4 u^4 +
  144 ce^2 wb^2 - 24 G Q^2 u^2 wb^2 - 80 de wbc^2 + 18 wbcd^3 -
  16 u^2 wc^3 + 16 G Q^2 wc^4}
```

How can I fix this?

The code as it should look.

[image]

Comment: What are you using to format it? And what're you using? - code fences (three backticks ``` or pre tags might work )

Comment: I used ```...```  as well as the indentation method (by selecting the code and doing the Ctrl - K)

Comment: Could you pop the original code somewhere that won't format it? Maybe a pastebin? And while its usually discouraged, a screenshot of how the code *should* look?

Comment: Sure, its a Mathematica code and I shall be able to screenshot and post since I am unaware about a place where '->' would be formatted as it is done in mathematica.

Comment: Are you trying to have this displayed as `code format` or some other formatting? What portion isn't being displayed correctly? Your "The code is this:" and "with the results like this" are completely different text, so it's unclear what or how you feel this isn't being displayed properly. Your "The code as it should look" image is largely how it does look, assuming you actually mean `code format`. If you mean something other than `code formatting`, then be specific as to what you are intending to produce. Are you trying to use MathJax (this doesn't really look like it)?

Comment: Are you meaning that you expect your text to be formatted on SE exactly as you see it in Mathematica? Is the issue that you're not seeing an automatic translation of `->` to `➞`? Are you expecting the line breaks in other locations? Are you expecting the syntax highlighting?

Comment: MSE isn’t letting me post the question based on formatting grounds even when I have particularly taken care of the code by all the means available. The code is not MathJax but Mathematica input.

Comment: Then, it's very hard for us to help you. Please show a screen shot, or shots, of *exactly* what is happening, both what you are trying to enter and any errors which are shown. It would be very helpful if you made the exact text you're trying to post available in some way, somewhere. Without more information from you, there's not much more we can do for you.

Comment: Understood. Even though the question I was ask there at MSE is figured out by me. Still I would like to know why I wasn’t able to post it.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* It looks close enough to what you're looking for and there's 2 ways to do this.

SE supports 'github' style code fences as below

````
```
{18 wbcd^3 - 192 w^2 bde^2 + 18 b^3 cde + 144 wb^2 ce^2 - 4 wc^3 d^2 +
b^2 c^2 d^2 - 4 b^3 d^3 - 27 w^2 d^4 - 80 wbc^2 de + 16 wc^4 e - 4 b^2 c^3 e + 144 w^2 cd^2 e - 6 wb^2 d^2 e - 27 b^4 e^2 - 128 w^2 c^2 e^2 + 256 w^3 e^3}/.{w -> a^2, b -> 2 a h ,c -> h^2 - 1, d -> 2 u , e -> G Q^2 }
```
````

Which gives you output like this -

```
{18 wbcd^3 - 192 w^2 bde^2 + 18 b^3 cde + 144 wb^2 ce^2 - 4 wc^3 d^2 +
b^2 c^2 d^2 - 4 b^3 d^3 - 27 w^2 d^4 - 80 wbc^2 de + 16 wc^4 e - 4 b^2 c^3 e + 144 w^2 cd^2 e - 6 wb^2 d^2 e - 27 b^4 e^2 - 128 w^2 c^2 e^2 + 256 w^3 e^3}/.{w -> a^2, b -> 2 a h ,c -> h^2 - 1, d -> 2 u , e -> G Q^2 }
```

You could also wrap it in pre tags

```
<pre>
{18 wbcd^3 - 192 w^2 bde^2 + 18 b^3 cde + 144 wb^2 ce^2 - 4 wc^3 d^2 +
b^2 c^2 d^2 - 4 b^3 d^3 - 27 w^2 d^4 - 80 wbc^2 de + 16 wc^4 e - 4 b^2 c^3 e + 144 w^2 cd^2 e - 6 wb^2 d^2 e - 27 b^4 e^2 - 128 w^2 c^2 e^2 + 256 w^3 e^3}/.{w -> a^2, b -> 2 a h ,c -> h^2 - 1, d -> 2 u , e -> G Q^2 }
</pre>
```

As below, which removes any form of formatting.

```
{18 wbcd^3 - 192 w^2 bde^2 + 18 b^3 cde + 144 wb^2 ce^2 - 4 wc^3 d^2 +
b^2 c^2 d^2 - 4 b^3 d^3 - 27 w^2 d^4 - 80 wbc^2 de + 16 wc^4 e - 4 b^2 c^3 e + 144 w^2 cd^2 e - 6 wb^2 d^2 e - 27 b^4 e^2 - 128 w^2 c^2 e^2 + 256 w^3 e^3}/.{w -> a^2, b -> 2 a h ,c -> h^2 - 1, d -> 2 u , e -> G Q^2 }
```

Wolfram seems to use this right arrow → - [as per the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/RightArrow.html) . While there's probably easier ways to do it, I just ganked it off the first google search for right arrow, and picked the right one based off the docs. [Happened to be this site](https://unicode-table.com/en/2192/)

As such, in theory you could probably use that

and get something like this

```
{18 wbcd^3 - 192 w^2 bde^2 + 18 b^3 cde + 144 wb^2 ce^2 - 4 wc^3 d^2 +
b^2 c^2 d^2 - 4 b^3 d^3 - 27 w^2 d^4 - 80 wbc^2 de + 16 wc^4 e - 4 b^2 c^3 e + 144 w^2 cd^2 e - 6 wb^2 d^2 e - 27 b^4 e^2 - 128 w^2 c^2 e^2 + 256 w^3 e^3}/.{w →  a^2, b →  2 a h ,c →  h^2 - 1, d →  2 u , e →  G Q^2 }
```

Comment: Still not working. My problem is less with the arrows and more with MSE won't accept my question even if I am using coding fences like I have done in the question?

Comment: OH! That thing. I'm not sure what's the solution there since I don't post much code. Add a screenshot of the error to your question - someone more code literate might have an idea